# Unit test with Subscription in a component with Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Unit test with Subscription in a component with Jasmine/Karma

I try to testing a component with Subscription, whose i'm using for obtain some data from service. I need to compare mock data with number "4", and if the comparision give out the true value, this  test will be passed. My problem is misunderstand how to check it correctly.

Component app-callorder-form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy,  } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormsService } from '../../services/forms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-callorder-form',
  templateUrl: './callorder-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./callorder-form.component.css']
})
export class CallorderFormComponent implements OnInit {

  modal_switcher: boolean = false; 
  subscription: Subscription;  

  constructor(private formsService: FormsService) {

    this.subscription = formsService.observableclicks$.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.typeofform == 4) {
        this.modal_switcher = true;
      }      
    }); 

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
  }
}
```

Service forms.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ClickForm } from '../classes/click-class'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormsService {

  private clicks = new Subject<ClickForm>(); 
  observableclicks$ = this.clicks.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //This method obtain values from another component
  openForm(openClick: ClickForm) {
    this.clicks.next(openClick);
  }  

}
```

Test

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CallorderFormComponent } from './callorder-form.component';
import { FormsService } from '../../services/forms.service';

describe('CallorderFormComponent', () => {
  let component: CallorderFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CallorderFormComponent>;
  let forms: FormsService;
  let spy: jasmine.Spy;  
  let subscription: Subscription;  

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CallorderFormComponent ],
      providers: [ FormsService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    forms = TestBed.get(FormsService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CallorderFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  //Problem is here
  it('...', async(() => {
    spy = spyOn(forms.observableclicks$, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(subscription);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(spy).toBe(4); 
    });
  }));

});
```

Comment: You expect a spy on a function to be the number 4?! I'd strongly recommend reading e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing to comprehend the basics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for your advice! After a detailed reading of the guide i was able to test the component without errors.

Comment: great! Good job.

Comment: @AlexSlav : In case you want to read more about unit testing in Angular, you can refer this series of articles https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working approach, i suppose:

```
  it('should have typeofform == 4', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const openClick: ClickForm = {typeofform: 4, typeofact: 'Some data'};
    forms.openForm(openClick);     
    forms.observableclicks$.subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data.typeofform).toBe(4);              
    });
    done();   
  });
```

**Update**:

```
  it('should have typeofform == 4', async((done: DoneFn) => {
    const openClick: ClickForm = {typeofform: 4, typeofact: 'Some data'};
    forms.openForm(openClick);     
    forms.observableclicks$.subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data.typeofform).toBe(4);
      done();               
    });      
  }));
```

Comment: Note that the done call should be *inside* the async callback, otherwise the expectation might not get reached. It's good practice to make sure a test can fail for the right reason before making it pass.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, and again thanks for your advice. I'm amended the answer.